# Solving a linear system of equations with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-algebra

Q) I have a finite state space $S$ of size $n$ and $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$. $A,B\subset S$. $L$ is a $n\times n$ matrix such that all row sums = $0$. Also $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$.

> I am trying to find a $f$, a vector of size $n$, such that $f$ satisfies $(Lf)_x=0$ for $x\not\in S\setminus\{A\cup B\}$ where $(Lf)_x$ is the value corresponding to state $x$ in the vector $Lf$ with the aforementioned boundary conditions, i.e. $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$, in Python. Any suggestions?

For example: let $S=\{0,1,2,3\}, f(0)=0, f(3)=1$
$$ L=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & -2 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

and solving $(Lf)_x=0$ for states $x=1,2$, we can see that

$$ Lf=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & -2 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 \\
    x_1  \\
    x_2  \\
    1  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    . \\
    0  \\
    0  \\
    .  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

i.e. $x_1=1/3, x_2=2/3$. That is $f(1)=1/3,f(2)=2/3$.

> So I want to be able to do this for a big matrix $L$ in Python.

Comment: Your example is just two linear equations in two unknowns, since the first and last row contribute nothing.  You can solve a system of linear equations in python using numpy.

Comment: @saulspatz May I know how to do that for a large $L$? Because I cannot use np.linalg.solve$(L,0)$ because the right side vector is not all zeroes and if I take the block matrix of $L$ leaving the sets $A$ and $B$, I wouldn't be able to multiply that with the vector $f$.

Comment: You have to figure out how to transform the problem into one that `linalg.solve` will handle.  In the example, the coefficient matrix will be `L[1:3,1:3]`.  You'll have to construct the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to program this is to pass the matrix $L$, the indices of the two dummy rows (in order), and the values in those two rows.  The  function would first delete the two dummy rows (rows $0$ and $3$ in the example.)

Then construct a vector $B$ of length $n-2$ as follows. Say the dummy indices are $a$ and $b$ and the associated values are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Then the value of $B[r]$ is `-\alpha*L[r,a]-\beta*L[r,b]`.  Finally, delete columns $a$ and $b$ from $L$ and solve $LX=B$.

Note that a simpler way to compute $B$ is

```
`B=-alpha*L[:,a]-\beta*L[:,b]`
```